# LibreOffice Base missing on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, database

I am an occasional user of Ubuntu & have upgraded to 11.10 (loved the prev 8.04 ) but Libre Office Base (I use databases a lot) is not available in the new Ubuntu from the Launcher.

1. Does it get installed as part of the package?
2. If it does how do I access it?
3. If not how do I install it?

Answer (score 6):

If it is not installed, you can install it with :

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base
```

Or for the entire metapackage

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice libreoffice-gnome
```

You can add it to the launcher (on the left) by dragging the icon from your dashboard (main menu) to the launcher.

See also :

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAcdFd0MmH0

Comment: I did read that but as I said "occasional User". Wyhere do I type that please?

Comment: You can type the code I entered in a terminal, use your log in password when prompted. Alternately you can use the software center and search for libreoffice.